# Memcpy crash depending on pointer type

Tags: c++, macos, crash, memcpy

I'm using this helper function to pack different data types into a single buffer:

```
template <class T>
static inline void PushBack(T& value, void*& buffer) {
    T* typedBuffer = (T*)buffer;
    memcpy(buffer, &value, sizeof(value));
    typedBuffer++;
    buffer = typedBuffer;
}
```

I'm calling in a loop with 12B and 16B vectors (3 or 4 floats), and it works fine.

However, my other approaches doesn't:

```
template <class T>
static inline void PushBack(T& value, void*& buffer) {
    T* typedBuffer = (T*)buffer;
    memcpy((T*)buffer, &value, sizeof(value)); //crash on 16B
    typedBuffer++;
    buffer = typedBuffer;
}

template <class T>
static inline void PushBack(T& value, void*& buffer) {
    T* typedBuffer = (T*)buffer;
    memcpy(typedBuffer, &value, sizeof(value)); //crash
    typedBuffer++;
    buffer = typedBuffer;
}

template <class T>
static inline void PushBack(T& value, void*& buffer) {
    T* typedBuffer = (T*)buffer;
    *typedBuffer = value; //crash
    typedBuffer++;
    buffer = typedBuffer;
}
```

Those three examples always crash while copying 16B value, after previously copying total amount of 36B with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (EXC_I386_GPFLT).

This was run on intel and was compiled as release (fastest, smallest). I wasn't able to check what's happening in the assembly yet.

When I copy only 16B vectors, the problem doesn't occur, so I assume this is related to fact that pointer is not aligned to 16B. I could understand it in the last case (copy via pointer to pointer), but why does it matter in memcpy?

Comment: Can you construct a complete test-case that demonstrates this?

Comment: I'm working on it. it seems that it works fine when extracted to other project.

Comment: What do you mean by vector?  An example will help.  Using memcpy is undefined behavior on types with non-trivial memory layouts.

Comment: It was struct containing 3 or 4 floats. I didn't notice in that one of structs was requesting alignment - I've found it after resolving macros in its definition. So - after all it's nothing special - hidden alignment caused crash.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - in one case struct from external library was forcing the alignment.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in post, the first approach that uses memcpy with void* destination (which works - doesn't do alignment check), while the others using T* destination does not. I initially missed the align requirement in struct I was putting in the buffer, so my question becomes rather meaningless.